# TPopupMenu as subcomponent, don't works

Tags: delphi, components, dropdownbutton, subcomponent

I'm trying to develop a component, specifically a button linked to a popup menu.
I can not understand why I do not see the PopupMenu.

Down here my code:

```
unit DropDownButton;

    interface

    uses
      System.SysUtils,
      System.Classes,
      Vcl.Controls,
      Vcl.StdCtrls,
      System.Types,
      Vcl.Menus;

    type
      TDropDownButton = class;

      TDropDownButton = class(TButton)
      private
        FDropDownMenu: TPopupMenu;
      protected
      public
        constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
        procedure Click; override;
      published
        property DropDownMenu: TPopupMenu read FDropDownMenu;
      end;

    procedure Register;

    implementation

    procedure Register;
    begin
      RegisterComponents('Flexline', [TDropDownButton]);
    end;

    constructor TDropDownButton.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
    begin
      inherited Create(AOwner);
      FDropDownMenu:= TPopupMenu.Create(Self);
      FDropDownMenu.Name:= 'Menu';
      FDropDownMenu.SetSubComponent(True);
    end;

    procedure TDropDownButton.Click;
    var
      _point: TPoint;
    begin
      _point:= Self.ClientToScreen(Point(0,0));
      FDropDownMenu.Popup(_point.X,_point.Y + Height);
      inherited Click;
    end;

    end.
```

Thanks in advance.

I'd like to make a dropdown button to use in my project

Comment: Did you add any items to the menu? FWIW I hope you're aware that TButton has a DropDownMenu property.

Comment: yes to both questions, my case is different: I have to create a button that creates the dropdown by myself, I can not have to create it myself every time.

Comment: @Sertac's point is that a popup menu will not appear if it has no items in it - there's no reason for it to popup if there is nothing to be selected. Your code sample shows an empty menu (no items added), which means it should not appear.

Comment: I add them design time (from the component I find in the property) but the number of items remains 0 at runtime ...

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You need to add an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your q.

Comment: @Martyn It's quite near actually. The problem is that the items added to the menu in the designer don't show up in the dfm file. Question needs to say that and it's good.